# tp-lik monitor mode error

Tags: kali-linux, drivers, usb, network-interface

I have a tp link usb network adapter and when I tried to enable monitor mode, I got something saying `SET failed on device wlan1 ; Invalid argument.` as I used `iwconfig`. Later on I found  [this link](https://nooblinux.com/how-to-enable-monitor-mode-on-tp-link-tl-wn722n-v2-v3/) to enable monitor mode for tp link, and i ran the commends following

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo reboot

sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

sudo apt install bc

sudo rmmod r8188eu.ko
```

after i ran `rmmod` my interface `wlan1` which is the usb adapter by tplink disappeared and never appeared back again.. How can I make it visible again? and I want to enable monitor mode, thank you for the help.. In case you are wondering, rest of the commands for the tutorial goes,

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus

cd rtl8188eus

sudo -i

echo "blacklist r8188eu" > "/etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf"

exit

reboot

cd rtl8188eus

make

sudo make install

sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

also, just in case, I have tp link model `TL-WN727N` and I am running kali linux.